# Send post request to another domain from server

Tags: spring, post

Is there any way in spring where I can POST the requests to another domain from My controller? I have parameters which I need to pass in POST from the controller to another third party domain, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is for your server to act like a HTTP *client* and send some data via HTTP POST to a third server:

```
Your web app client ---> Your web server ---> Another web server
```

If that is indeed what you need, yes, it is possible. The fact that your application is a web server itself isn't important, although it can be confusing - it's easier to think about it as if you wanted to post the data from an ordinary command-line Java application.

One of the many tools that can help you is [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).

Comment: thanks for your comment, but in my case--- I reached the spring controller, from there I have to go to another URL and need to post the parameters in that, is this possible, thanks

Comment: @user2907217 I'm not sure why that would prevent you from using the approach I mentioned. You should probably edit your question to highlight exactly what you need and why using a HTTP client won't work for you.

Comment: @user2907217 or is just redirecting to the third party server what you actually need, with no other logic in your controller?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I need to redirect to a third party server, but I need to pass parameters which cannot be passed as query parameters in GET